# Ignore re-generated but unchanged files in a Subversion commit

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

We use Entity Framework 5. Sometimes we find if we make a change to the model all class files are deleted and re-created, although most of them contain exactly the same code as before.

Subversion marks all these files as deleted/new and, when committed, uploads a new version of all of them, regardless of whether their contents have actually changed. This is annoying as it makes it difficult to track which files have actually changed.

Is there any way to make subversion include in the commit only those files that have actually changed?

We are using TortoiseSVN 1.7.11, Build 23600; and AnkhSVN 2.3.10838.1211 with Visual Studio Professional 2012

Comment: We found the behaviour from EF 5 only happened when there was an error in the model - This made EF to delete all files, and regenerate them only when all errors are corrected. So what we do now is to restore all files from SVN, then resave the model, so only the files with model changes are recreated.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can use subversion hooks and prohibit remove/add files with identical names in same revision. Then user will be responsible to convert 'replace' to 'modify'. This is also annoying, but will be better look in history, better merged and updated.

Comment: Hello Sergey, Thanks for your suggestion. It provides a slight improvement, but also I think it just moves the pain elsewhere, rather than improving efficiency.

Comment: Well, you can ask AnkhSVN developers if they can detect this situation (recreate same file) and do not perfrom add/delete operation. May be even such option already exists (I never used AnkhSVN)

Comment: Coming to think about it, these files should not be under source control at all, really. They are generated by the EF templates, so in a way they are a build artifact, not original source. I'll work out how to get them ignored altogether and post an answer here.

Comment: I am noit so sure. If, for example, you will build project with msbuild as part of continuous integration, these files will not be generated. Need to check though.